# Java android NFC Start scanning on button click

Tags: java, android, nfc

Currently i'm creating an android java project that allow the app to start scaning nfc Tag **on button click**. I already know how to start scan NFC tag on app start. But doesn't know how to only start scanning on button click. Please help me. thankyou

Answer (score 0):

The answer is not to start scanning on button click, as it provides a very poor user experience.

Instead it's best to use `enableReaderMode` to start scanning when your app starts, then the button click just changes the behaviour of what your app does when a Tag is detected.

e.g. the Handle Tag process is:-

Handle Tag if button NOT click then do nothing

or

Handle Tag if button click then do whatever you want to do

Thus it looks like you are only scanning when button is clicked but you don't get the system default popups or other NFC apps overriding your app if the user presents the Tag at the wrong time.